# C# - Change Location of Custom Control inside GroupBox (returns null reference exception)

Tags: c#, location, nullreferenceexception, groupbox

I am working on a project where I have designed a custom control, and I am trying to add it to and locate it within a group box.

The steps of initialising and adding the control to the box work fine, but then anything I attempt to move or resize the control causes an exception.

```
        //initialise using object in outputs collection
        VitalsVisual vitalsVisual = vitalOutputs.getVitalsVisual();
        //add to relevant groupbox
        grpbxIntraOp.Controls.Add(vitalsVisual);
        //change location (coordinates within groupbox)
        vitalsVisual.Location = new Point(249, 256); //THROWS EXCEPTION
        //resize
        vitalsVisual.Size = new Size(494, 342); //THROWS EXCEPTION IF REACHED
```

All I get on either of the indicated lines is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I don't really understand this, as it would point to the `VitalsVisual vitalsVisual` not being initialised, but the constructor is called and the `Controls.Add()` command is working. Surely if it had not been initialised, this command would throw the same exception.

Can anybody spot what might be wrong here? Would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction!

Thanks, Mark

Comment: Does `getVitalsVisual` actually return a value or does it return null? What does the `VitalsVisual` control inherit from?

Comment: The proposed answer explains why you've failed to debug this correctly, but doesn't really solve the _problem_, i.e. that you have a null reference. Please review the extensive advice found in the marked duplicate for how to debug a `NullReferenceException`, so that you can get to a point where your question is more specific than "why am I getting this exception?" If you still have problems at that point, ask a new question in which you've provided a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, along with a precise explanation of what _specifically_ you're having trouble with.

Comment: Not a duplicate as he had wrongly assumed that a control had could add to a Controls collection can't be null. I have explained why this is a wrong assumption. Debugging the `getVitalsVisual` is the next step, but not the question here, really..

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, but that is by design.

Test:

```
Button button = null;
this.Controls.Add(button);
button.Location = Point.Empty;
```

This does just the same, i.e. it throws at the **last** line, not when **adding**..

So it is allowed **trying** to add `null` objectes to a `Controls` collection.

I wrote 'trying' because the `Controls.Add` actually **fails quietly**:

```
Button button = null;
Console.WriteLine( this.Controls.Count + " controls now.";
this.Controls.Add(button);
Console.WriteLine( "Still " + this.Controls.Count + " controls.";
```

No changes in the count.

A look at the [sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,15891d0ad5731bb2) confirms this:

> `public virtual void Add(Control value) {
>                   if (value == null)
>                       return;
>      ...`

So to sum up: your function surely returns a null object but the error is suppressed. Is it a bug or a feature?